# How to disable dhcpd default gateway for mobile device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, android, dnsmasq

I use `hostapd` on a Raspberry Pi to create a Wi-Fi hotspot for a special purpose. It doesn't connect to the internet: It just provides a local network.

I want to connect a mobile device to my hotspot. But when my mobile device is connected to my hotspot, Android disables cellular data. iPhone works fine; it connects to my hotspot and uses cellular data to get to the Internet successfully.

I want my mobile device to both connect to my hotspot and use cellular data to get to the Internet.

I tried `isc-dhcp-server`, `dnsmasq`, and `udhcpd`, but the results were the same with all servers.

Comment: Did you turned the standard gateway option off or not in your DHCP server? If you turned it off and it did not help, then it sounds like a Android bug (aka feature). For iSC it is the `option router ...` entry in `dhcpd.conf` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but nothing changed.